# How to get/set value for DataGridViewButtonColumn in cell?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datagridview

I tried to set value for `DataGridViewButtonColumn` cell in Datagridview.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{

if (dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Equals("id")) {
   e.Value = 14;
}            
}
```

Then I try to get value after click event:

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
 {
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex.Equals(1) && e.RowIndex != -1)
    {
      // GET HERE 
    }
}
```

So, how to get value `e.Value = 14` in event `dataGridView1_CellClick`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var dg = (DataGridView)sender;
    dg[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value = 123;
}
```